# Progress bar update with on demand resources

Tags: swift, progress-bar

Hi all I am trying to find out more info on getting the progress bar to work in swift. I just can't seem to find info on it that makes sense its either in Objective C or for TV.

below is the code I'm using to download the assists. any help would be appreciated.

```
 request = NSBundleResourceRequest(tags: [tag])
    request.beginAccessingResources { (error) in
        //  Called on background thread
        if error == nil {

            }
            OperationQueue.main.addOperation({ () -> Void in
               self.continueBtton.isEnabled = true
            })


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you create the request, do:

```
request = NSBundleResourceRequest(tags: [tag])
let progressView = UIProgressView()
progressView.observedProgress = request.progress
// add progressView to UI somehow
```

Then, when you enable the `continueButton` you can also remove the `progressView`.

Comment: thank you for the info @DaveWeston. when i put the code in it says cannot assign type progress to Float.

Comment: I updated the code to correct that issue, it should have been `UIProgressView.observedProgress` instead of just `progress`.

Comment: Wow so simple, Thank you so much for this info i have been tearing my hair out for 2 days on it struggling to find info that made sense to my code, i have only been doing iOS for 6 months. I removed the let progressView = progressView() because i had already put that further up when i added the progress view in the storyboard. but after that it worked. One line of code is all it needed. Thank you sooo much!!!